# 1990s/2000s PC strategy game in which you build a village, discover new lands, and fight knights

Tags: story-identification, video-games, medieval

I'm looking for a game that I used to play in the early 2000s. It was a strategy game like *[Medieval: Total War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medieval:_Total_War)*.

I remember that I needed to build a village and start procreating. I remember also a wizard in the game and, when you were discovering new lands, you needed to fight with some knights, but you just had stones to fight against them, and your wizard.

I remember that the intro of the game was like a dragon, or something like that, destroying a village.

Comment: You mention Medieval: Total War. Does this mean that it had a separate turn-based game on a map, and battles were then fought separately in real time? Was the entire game played on one big map, or was the main map abstracted with battles played in "zoomed-in" maps, separating the strategic and tactical parts of the game, like in Total War? Was it even turn-based or real-time?

Answer (score 12):

This sounds like [Stronghold Legends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stronghold_Legends), the mythological edition of the [Stronghold series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stronghold_(series)) of medieval strategy games.

> I'm looking for a game that I used to play in the early 2000s. It was a strategy game like Medieval: Total War.

It came out in 2006 so a bit late, but the series started in 2001. The Stronghold series is a real-time strategy and base building game that is mostly medieval themed, and was released around the same time as the early Total War games.

> I remember that I needed to build a village and start procreating.

The main economic gameplay side of the Stronghold series is to build up a medieval village and protect it, and that includes growing your villager population.

> I remember also a wizard in the game and, when you were discovering new lands, you needed to fight with some knights, but you just had stones to fight against them, and your wizard.

From Wikipedia's description of the plot of the first campaign:

> This storyline follows King Arthur and his Knights of the Round Table. Merlin frequently becomes a necessary part of the campaign.

Merlin is a wizard, the main friendly characters of that first campaign are the Knights of the Round Table, and since it's a medieval setting your opponents often have knights and other armored units.

I played this game a long time ago and can't remember stones being a particularly important weapon, but a major part of the gameplay is building stone castles, and there are catapult/trebuchet/etc. units that hurl rocks.

> I remember that the intro of the game was like a dragon, or something like that, destroying a village.

Not quite, the intro to Stronghold Legends has a dragon but not a village. The intro includes a giant destroying a castle wall, Arthur pulling the sword from a stone, and ends with a dragon roaring at the camera. That dragon could be what you're remembering, and I wouldn't be surprised if there's a cutscene later in the game with a destroyed village:

([Stronghold II's intro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A0KEksazpuU) includes more traditional village/castle siege but doesn't have a dragon, so maybe you're conflating the two?)

Answer (score 7):

### [Total Annihilation: Kingdoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_Annihilation:_Kingdoms)

Things that fit:

- **Time period**
- **Fantasy Setting**
- **Wizard**
- **Dragon in Launch Cutscene**

Kingdoms was released in 1999, with DLC released in 2000, that would seem to fit with early 2000s.

Along with the fantasy setting, the player avatar is a mage/wizard.
The dragon is not in the opening gameplay, but is part of the game launch credits.

[Gameplay Vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yDO_r7RquNM)

Answer (score 1):

If it’s a *really* old game, it could be [*Conqueror A.D. 1086*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conqueror_A.D._1086). You could conquer all the England or kill the Dragon. Alternatively, it could be the [*Master of Magic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_of_Magic) or [*Heroes of Might and Magic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroes_of_Might_and_Magic).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

It could be [*Lords of Magic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lords_of_Magic). It released in 1996, and had several sequels.

It was a turn-based strategy game similar to Total War games. It's a fantasy setting. The game has both wizards and dragons, although, I can't remember if a dragon was in any of the opening cutscenes.

You send soldiers out to explore the map and battle with monsters for control of resources and points of interest around the map, then defend them from other players and random monsters.

There were 8 different factions players could choose from, and each faction has a unique hero/leader and unique buildings and soldier units they can build and recruit.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.   You could improve your answer by finding some links to images from the game, or possibly a youtube video, that would help the asker recognize this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Populous: the beginning? Rings a bell but wasn't super popular.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to explain why you think this is the answer (e.g., what matches the question description, images, etc.).

Comment: Welcome to [Science Fiction & Fantasy SE](/tour)! Please [edit] your answer to add more details on how this work answers the question. You can find [tips on how to write a good story identification answer and what details to add in our guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9444/7957).